# How to access tcp header details?

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, tcp, header

Like I have created socket and bound that socket to the client side. I am able to connect two sides and able to send any amount of data.Its basically TCP socket. My problem is that I want to access TCP header details to check and set parameters for some kind of operation.
But am not able to do that .I am working in user space. From the socket level I want to access header part.. Can you please help me on this....It would be great if help me..

Comment: When you are creating the socket, dont you create the header? If you are using a library to create the socket, doesnt the library have API to get the header info?

Comment: @badmaash Most socket APIs does not give you access to that directly when you're creating a TCP socket.

Comment: There is no point of using TCP socket if you want to explicitly change its header values.. unless you need to run some experiments.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want raw sockets. Here's a document on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note that access to raw sockets is limited; I'm don't think they are available for non-admins.